# Python: find index for a value that apears more than once

Tags: python-2.7, indexing

I have the string "DARPA", and I want to know the index of every value.
The .index() returns only the first occurrence. How can I get the index for the second 'A'?
It is part of this code:

```
L = ["DARPA","DA","ARPRPA"]
my = []
for i in L:
    if len(i)>= 3:
      my.append(i)
a = []
for i in my:
    for char in i,:
        a.append(i[i.index(char):i.index(char)+3])
C = []
for i in a:
    if len(i) == 3:
        C.append(i)
print C
```

that its output should be ['DAR', 'ARP', 'RPA', 'ARP', 'RPR', 'PRP', 'RPA'], usinf only for loop.

Comment: Please format the code, and mark the language you are using.

Answer (score 1):

You dont need to know the index of each element, what you need is the length of the entries and you have correctly calculated that using len(). 
The desired result can be achieved by

```
print_len=3
var = ["DARPA","DA","ARPRPA"]
for w in var:
    if len(w)>3:
        start=0
        w_len=len(w)+1
        for i in range(print_len,w_len):
            print w[start:i]
            start=start+1
```

if you still need the index of all characters, you can use something like:

```
s='thisismywordwithrepeatsinthewords'
for index,char in enumerate(s):
    print index,char
```

Mixing the two snippets would give something like:

```
print_len=3
var = ["DARPA","DA","ARPRPA"]
for w in var:
    if len(w)>3:
        for i,c in enumerate(w[:len(w)-2]):
            print w[i:i+3]
```

Comment: Thank you! That was really helpful.Do you have any suggestions to add to my code in order to make in work?

Answer (score 0):

had better understand what to do before code

just get the output easily:

```
var = ["DARPA","DA","ARPRPA"]
for w in var:
    if len(w)>3:
        for i in range(len(w)-2):
            print w[i:i+3]
```